# NetBeans shortcut key to see Maven variable value

Tags: maven, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut key in NetBeans that will allow me to see the value of variables used in a Maven pom.xml file?

Example:
If I place my mouse in the variable "${junit.version}" in this snippet:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

is there some key combination I could press to see the current value of the "junit.version" variable?

I already know that I can place the cursor just after `<version>` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to see the available versions, but I would like a way to compare that to the current version of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke a 'hyperlink' with the cursor on top of ${junit.version}. A tooltip should appear giving you the defined (resolved) value and following the hyperlink will lead you to where the property is defined. On mac the hyperlink is triggered by pressing 'Command' while hovering on top of the expression. Other platforms use similar keys (Ctrl, Alt - not entirely sure which one)

Comment: Thanks!  On Windows one must press "Ctrl" while hovering the mouse over the variable.  Don't know why I couldn't figure that out myself.